# Next-intl useTranslations Problem Not working in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next-intl

I have created a custom component for translating text by next-intl the component is below but when importing the component in server component it gives me error how to fixed it?

```js
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

const Translations = ({ children }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslations();

  return t(children);
};

export default Translations;
```